# Can you say "everything is good" as well was "everything is well"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, adjective-phrases

Is it grammatically correct to say "everything is good"? And why is "everything is well" correct? Isn't "well" an adverb?

Edit: I'm looking for an answer for this phrase specifically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do "well" and "good" mean the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337/when-do-well-and-good-mean-the-same) Also [“I did well” vs. “I did good”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/), [“I feel well” vs “I feel good”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/185106/i-feel-well-vs-i-feel-good), [difference in “good” and “well” in this sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212905/), [Difference between 'good' and 'well'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9451/) and probably others.

Comment: Note that ***everything is well*** is non-idiomatic (or ungrammatical, depending on how you see such things). But ***everyone is well*** is fine, because in that context, ***well*** means ***healthy, not sick***.

Comment: And yet **all is well** is well established.

Comment: Interestingly, Google Books Ngram viewer has **everything is well** and **everything is good** neck and neck.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everything+is+good%2Ceverything+is+well&year_

Comment: Very interesting @RonaldSole. I think that answers is actually.

Comment: I completely disagree that *everything is well* is unidiomatic. It sounds just fine to me—and I've heard it said by various people. (However, *good* and *well* do mean subtly different things.)